# With Excel Conditional Formatting - Want to Highlight Cells in a range that match any from another range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting, countif

Sheet One has 5 cells in a row with numbers. (A2:F2)

Sheet Two also has 5 cells in a row with numbers. (A3:F3)

I'd like to highlight sheet one's cells yellow every time that sheet two has a matching number entered. (There will be more rows of data added to each sheet, but I am using the first row only, to keep it simple.

It works with creating a CF equals to, but I need something that applies to a range of data, from a range of data to make this less tedious. Thank you for any tips!

I am using conditional formatting. I have tried Vlookup, Match, and Countif, but I am new to this type of formatting.

(Sheet two's numbers can be placed in a list (column), instead of a row, if that matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$F,A2)>0
```

Snapshot of Sheet1 and the Conditional Formatting:

[image]

Snapshot of Sheet2:

[image]

Comment: Hello again, is it possible to use SumProduct to add up the number of highlighted cells in each row? And to place the result at the end of each row. Thank you!

Comment: @Bekka [yes, it's possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5c0n.png) if you have everything the same as in the conditions of your question (which relies on the matching on Sheet2 rather than on the conditional formatting that was applied -- in which case it would require VBA). Or if you meant to get a count of the number of highlighted cells for each row, then simply remove the row by 1 (in the picture, it would be replace `A2:F2` at the end by 1)